# Is there a manifold $X$ with $H_3(X)\neq 0$ that can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I think there is no manifold $X$ with $H_1(X)\neq 0$ that can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}$, although I am not sure.

I thought there is a manifold $X$ with $H_2(X)\neq 0$ that can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$, such as a torus. However, this is wrong since torus cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$. How can I answer this question? Here, I mean $H_n(X)$ by the n-th homology group of the space $X$.

Simiarly, is there a manifold $X$ with $H_3(X)\neq 0$ that can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$? If there is, can we generalize this further?

Comment: How does a torus embed in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Perhaps I was wrong and it cannot be, although I would like to understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $M$ be a topological manifold with $H_n(M)\neq0$. I claim $M$ can not be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since homology vanishes in dimensions above $\dim(M)$, we see that $\dim(M)\ge n$. Assume $M$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Restricting this to a chart of $M$, we obtain an embedding of $\mathbb{R}^{\dim(M)}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. By invariance of domain, $\dim(M)\le n$. In total, $\dim(M)=n$. But then, again by invariance of domain, the embedded image of $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is open. Thus, $M$ is non-compact (since $M$ is non-empty and the only compact, open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the empty set). However, for a non-compact $n$-manifold, we have $H_n(M)=0$, contradiction.

For $n=1$, you could also argue explicitly that the only manifolds embedding in $\mathbb{R}$ are disjoint unions of points and disjoint unions of copies of $\mathbb{R}$, all of which have vanishing $H_1$.